# Ho do I solve chrome error for karma tests for Angular with gitlab CI?

Tags: angular, ubuntu, continuous-integration, gitlab, karma-runner

I try to run karma tests for Angular with gitlab CI.

The .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: node:14.0.0

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - npm install
  - apt-get update -qq
  - apt-get install -y -qq rsync
  - apt-get install -y -qq sshpass
  - wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
  - apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb -y

stages:
  - testing_deploy


build_and_deploy_testing:
  stage: testing_deploy
  script:
    - echo "============== ADD DEVELOP SSH KEY =============="
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
    - echo "============== START BUILD AND DEPLOY TESTING =============="
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --progress false --watch=false
```

And I get a failed job message:

```
12 01 2021 16:25:31.828:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
    [2172:2172:0112/162531.552480:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

12 01 2021 16:25:31.829:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout: 
12 01 2021 16:25:31.829:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr: [2172:2172:0112/162531.552480:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

12 01 2021 16:25:31.840:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

How to solve ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

When using the Docker executor, the container runs as whatever user the image creators defined, which is almost always `root`; the gitlab runner doesn't set the user to `root`. There have been requests to make this configurable in the step configuration, but a maintainer pointed out that you can create a custom image based on the image you need.

So for example, let's say the user defined for the image `mysql:8` is `root`, but I need to run something as the `mysql` user. Here's an example Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:8

USER mysql
```

This image is build on top of `mysql:8`, but we change the user it runs as. You can build the image by running `docker build mysql_custom_image`. If successful, at the end of the output you'll get something like `Successfully built h47841j5285`. Then you can give it a more friendly name: `docker tag h47841j5285 my_org/mysql_custom_image`.

If you're using Gitlab's built-in registry, you can then push it up there, or to hub.docker.com. If not, you can copy the Dockerfile to your runners and build it on each of them.

Your new .gitlab-ci.yml file would look something like:

```
image: my_org/mysql_custom_image
...
```